# VBA Subroutine doesn't exit for loop

Tags: vba, plc, scada

I’m new to programing so I’m hoping you can help me. Not sure how to formulate the right question so I didn’t find any StackOverflow answers.

When I step through this code and come to OpcServObj.Connect OpcServerStrg it doesn't connect. I get no errors, nothing appears to happen. Cursor jumps to the left margin and does nothing. Only when I resume stepping through the routine it starts the function over again. It should continue and exit the for loop where I plan to test the state of the connection again.

Reference Library:
OPC DA Automation Wrapper 2.02

```
Sub Main()
ConnectOPC
End Sub

Private Function ConnectOPC() As Boolean

Dim OpcServObj As OPCAutomation.OPCServer            
Dim OpcGroupObj As OPCAutomation.OPCGroup            

Dim OPCServerlist As Variant
Dim OpcServerStrg As String

Set OpcServObj = New OPCAutomation.OPCServer          
OPCServerlist = OpcServObj.GetOPCServers

If OpcServObj.ServerState <> True Then

    For i = 1 To UBound(OPCServerlist) 

       OpcServerStrg = OPCServerlist(i)

         If OpcServerStrg = "ICONICS.IconicsOPCUAServer.V5" Then

            OpcServObj.Connect OpcServerStrg

            Exit For

         End If

    Next i

End If

End Function
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the line:

```
If OpcServerStrg = "ICONICS.IconicsOPCUAServer.V5" Then
```

if the value in the variable **`OpcServerStrg`** is **not** equal to **`"ICONICS.IconicsOPCUAServer.V5"`** then the code will loop again to the top of the **`For`** loop and execute **`OpcServerStrg = OPCServerlist(i)`** again. The **`Exit For`** will not be seen.

When you say you **`step through this code`**... is it possible that you have a breakpoint set on the line: **`OpcServerStrg = OPCServerlist(i)`**, and you are clicking run (untill breakpoint) instead of clicking to single-step through the code?

Try setting a breakpoint at the line:

```
If OpcServerStrg = "ICONICS.IconicsOPCUAServer.V5" Then
```

then examine the value of **`OpcServerStrg`** when the program reaches the breakpoint and stops.

Comment: value of OpcServerStrg does get satisfied. It's when I execute the OpcServObj.Connect (OpcServerStrg) I having the issue.

Comment: The value at the breakpoint is "ICONICS.IconicsOPCUAServer.V5"

Comment: I put a breakpoint on the exit for and then continued stepping through the program. Thanks.